# Find a proper way to remove search onbackpress fragment

Tags: android, fragment, loading, fragment-backstack

I'm developing an application that involves fragments. There are three fragments

- Item List fragment
- Item details fragment
- Search/Loading fragment

Everything works well until the user press onbackbutton. I would like to show the user the previous fragment before the search fragment was shown. 
I tried few solutions but none of them seems to work for me. I tried to remove the search fragment manually from back stuck but I got weird situation that the previous and the current fragment were shown at the same time.

This is the function that replaces the fragments from the main activity

```
public void replaceFragment(Class<?> fragClass, Bundle b)
{
    Fragment bf = null;
    try
    {
        bf = (Fragment) fragClass.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (b != null)
    {
        bf.setArguments(b);
    }

    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    String backStateName = bf.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if (f != null && backStateName.equals(f.getClass().getSimpleName()))
    {
        return;
    }

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    _currentFragment = bf;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right);

    if(backStateName.equals(LoadingFragment.class.getSimpleName()))
    {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
    else
    {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bf).addToBackStack(backStateName).commit();
    }
}
```

onbackpress function

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
    {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead  of this, maintain all your fragment in stack and use add() instead of replace() method of Fragment Transaction  to add fragment.It will give you full control on navigation life cycle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours of figuring this out. I came across a simple solution, basically each time when I'm loading a new fragment I'm checking if the current fragment is the search fragment if so I will remove it manually by using popBackStackImmediate(). Not the most elegant solution but it worked for me.

This is my new function.

```
public void replaceFragment(Class<?> fragClass, Bundle b)
{
    BaseFragment bf = null;
    try
    {
        bf = (BaseFragment) fragClass.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (b != null)
    {
        bf.setArguments(b);
    }

    Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    String backStateName = bf.getClass().getSimpleName();
    if (f != null && backStateName.equals(f.getClass().getSimpleName()))
    {
        return;
    }

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    _currentFragment = bf;
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    if (f != null && f.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(LoadingFragment.class.getSimpleName()))
    {
        manager.popBackStackImmediate();
    }

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, bf, backStateName);
    ft.addToBackStack(backStateName);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();

}
```